# Is incompatible Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and SSD (Crucial)?

Tags: 20.04, ssd, inspiron

I recently installed a 480 GB BX500 SSD - Crucial, in a Dell Inspiron 5547 and installed a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

In the early days  the ubuntu was booting but my cooler was working all time (temperature beetween: 50º C and 65º C), and sometimes the booting was failing not recognizing HD.

For the past few days, I was passing  through grub but it was crashing at gnome startup (just black screen).

If I started as root in command line (using grub, not starting gnome but using recovery mode and so on) my ssd work pretty good, and temperature remains below 53º C.

I don't find any discussion or text about incompatibility beetween gnome (or ubuntu 20.0.4)  and SSD ( as in my configuration).

Any body knows some tips to me?  How to solute it?

Comment: If it seems to be a heat issue, make sure that all the air vents of your laptop are cleaned out as well as any fans by using compressed air.  If still getting too warm, look into using a cooling pad for under the laptop.

Comment: "*sometimes the booting was failing not recognizing HD*" suggests an intermittent hardware fault, not a problem with Ubuntu. Troubleshoot your hardware: Check your SSD's connection to the mainboard. Cables and connectors go bad. Try a different port, if possible. Check your power supply, if you have the tools. On occasion, an SSD leaves the factory faulty; that's why manufacturers have warranties.

Comment: SSDs and HDDs are all compatible with all OSs.  Some SSDs can work better with Ubuntu with firmware updates, but they will work.